# Google auth login

Tags: django, google-api

Well, I want to implement google auth login stuff with my django website.

I know there are some plugins can do this, but let's forget them for a moment and see how to implement from beginning.

I have read some articles about how to do this. I found a google document that explain how to create a google+ login button.

https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/#using_the_client-side_flow

I think it is great, but, for some reason, I don't want google+, I just need google. I just need user be able to login with their google account (not gmail but some particular domain).

I believe it shouldn't be too hard. I just curious does google provide such document to let user login with google account rather than google+.

Answer (score 0):

Google has changed their approach towards how user accounts are managed and user for various purposes, so I believe this is only way to do it.

See here: http://www.businessinsider.com/googlesign-in-2013-2

or here: http://googleplusplatform.blogspot.com/2013/02/google-plus-sign-in.html

Comment: Ha, didn't expect someome answer this ancient post:) I have figured out how to do it and have implemented it half years ago~~~Thanks for your advice:)